# How to get the bottle on the tower near the railway in Go West, Young Raccoon?

Tags: sly-cooper-thieves-in-time

How do I get the bottle on the tower near the railway in Sly Cooper Thieves in Time, Go West, Young Raccoon? I've tried climbing the tower, using the paraglider, using different characters; all unsuccessful. Do you need to buy a power up or gain an ability?

[image: bottle on the tower near the railway in Sly Cooper Thieves in Time, Go West, Young Raccoon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the two flagstaffs on the side of the building. The first will catapult you to the second and the second enables you to reach the roof and in further consequence the bottle. I've marked the spots in the image:
[image]

Comment: I should downvote you for not using freehand circles ;)

Comment: Next time, I promise :D

Comment: Amazing. I tried that a few times.. now it worked though. Thanks!